# Cannot scan for WiFi networks with BCM4321

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 14.10, broadcom

I believe I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) guide for installing WiFi drivers for my Broadcom 4321 chipset, but alas I still get the following:

```
arjun@perseus:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     No scan results
```

For all your debugging needs here are [the results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18871107/wireless-info.txt) from [this handy script](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qjc87hzk1z5x6z0/wireless_script) which essentially dumps all the system information possible related to WiFi.

If it helps, this is Ubuntu 14.10, 64-bit with kernel 3.16.0-23-generic on a 1st generation MacBook Air.
Someone somewhere get this thing onto a WiFi network please.

Comment: Have you tried the bcmwl-kernel-source module as http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/ says your chipset is only partially supported by the b43 module

Comment: @Jeremy31 That is the first thing I tried :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if your ethernet driver is *b44*. If so, we will use that information in a possible later step.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Next, I suggest, for your rather rare and lightly documented wireless device, that we try the proprietary driver:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it turns out that your ethernet driver is *b44*, it will now effectively be blacklisted. Please try:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. There is a line there that reads:

```
blacklist ssb
```

Comment it out like this:

```
#blacklist ssb
```

Proofread, save and close the text editor. If your ethernet driver is *not b44*, this step is unnecessary.

Reboot and tell us if the wireless and ethernet are working.

Comment: This appears to work, so long as you make sure you have the latest kernel (for me, 3.16.0-33-generic x86_64 is working).

Comment: And another problem gets burnt by chillies!  ;-) (Upvoted)